# Are there diseases which are contagious but can also arise simultaneously in an individual?

Tags: disease-transmission, pathophysiology

Diseases like most cancers are known to be not contagious; they arise `from within'. On the other hand, diseases like the flu are known to be contagious. Are there also diseases which fit in both categories?

Comment: Welcome Reimann. This is not just a question and answer site, we are expected to shoe the results of our own research and attempt to answer the question here. You might start by looking at [clonally transmissible cancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonally_transmissible_cancer) for starters, then rework the question to ask us to fill-in any gaps in what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease is an example.

In Creutzfeldt–Jakob, a spontaneous misfolding of a protein in the brain gives rise to a prion. A prion is a misfolded protein that is able to 'transmit' its pathological shape onto the normal variant of the same protein. The disease progresses as more and more proteins become misfolded. This is known as ***sporadic*** Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease [1].

When a healthy person comes in contact with the tissue containing the prions, they can get Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease too. (For example, a pathologist performing an autopsy.) This is known as ***acquired*** Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease [2].

---

[1] Kumar, V., Abbas, A. K., Aster, J. C., & Robbins, S. L. (2013). Robbins Basic Pathology (9th ed.). (pp. 831-832). Elsevier Gezondheidszorg.
[2] "Creutzfeldt-Jakob Disease Fact Sheet", NINDS, Publication date May 2018. - NIH Publication No. 18-NS-2760. https://www.ninds.nih.gov/Disorders/Patient-Caregiver-Education/Fact-Sheets/Creutzfeldt-Jakob-Disease-Fact-Sheet